# Calling imported functions results in xor eax, eax ret

Tags: c++, google-chrome, opengl-es, x86, mingw

I built *Google*'s *ANGLE* library (32bit, patched using [this patches](https://github.com/Martchus/PKGBUILDs/tree/master/angleproject/mingw-w64)) using MinGW-w64 from msys2 on Windows 7 (64bit). Namely static version with samples. It seems that by default *ANGLE* uses directly *OpenGL* by default (header `<gl31.h>`).

When I run sample (say, `hello_triangle.exe`) is creates a black window, then nothing happens.

I tried to debug the sample step by step using disassembly and found out, that every call to *OpenGL*'s funcion (`glViewport`, `glClearColor`, `glClear` etc) finally leads to execution of dummy stub fallback code.

Say, the call of `glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` looks like below:

```
fld1
fstps  0xc(%esp)
fldz
fstps  0x8(%esp)
fldz
fstps  0x4(%esp)
fld1
fstps  (%esp)
mov    0x40d398,%eax
call   *%eax
sub    $0x10,%esp // !
```

On `call *%eax` line it jumps to the next code:

```
mov    %fs:0x18,%edx
cmpl   $0x40,0x5214102c
jae    0x520a20e9 <glClearColor+32>
mov    %edx,%eax
add    0x5214100c,%edx
mov    (%edx),%edx
jmp    *0x338(%edx)
```

Final unconditional jump executes the following code:

```
xor %eax, %eax
ret $0x10
```

Which, in turn, returns to line, marked `// !` above.

First conditional jump is skipped due to condition is not matched (why?) and executes dummy fallback code.

I built the sample as follows (generated by *Qt Creator*'s `qbs` project):

```bash
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -m32 -g -O0 -w -pipe -fexceptions -MMD -MF -msse2 ^
    "--param=ssp-buffer-size=4" -ggdb "-Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2" -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DANGLE_WINDOWS_XP_SUPPORT ^
    -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DANGLE_STANDALONE_BUILD -DGL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DEGL_EGLEXT_PROTOTYPES -DNDEBUG ^
    -IC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/src ^
    -IC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/src/common/third_party/numerics ^
    -IC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/sysinclude ^
    -IC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/include ^
    -IC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/samples/sample_util ^
    -IC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/util ^
    "-std=c++0x" ^
    -o C:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/angle/build-angle-Desktop-Debug/qtc_Desktop__6e009929-debug/hello-triangle.qtc-Desktop--6e009929.6d1cc0e4/.obj/9ff4caaf6aae2e40/HelloTriangle.cpp.o ^
    -c C:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/samples/hello_triangle/HelloTriangle.cpp
C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe ^
    "-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs" ^
    "-Wl,-subsystem,console" ^
    -LC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/build-i686-w64-mingw32-shared/out/Release/samples ^
    -LC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/build-i686-w64-mingw32-shared/out/Release/src ^
    -LC:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/PKGBUILDs/angleproject/mingw-w64/src/angleproject/build-i686-w64-mingw32-shared/out/Release/util ^
    "-Wl,--stack,10485760" ^
    -o C:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/angle/build-angle-Desktop-Debug/qtc_Desktop__6e009929-debug/hello-triangle.qtc-Desktop--6e009929.6d1cc0e4/hello_triangle.exe ^
    C:/Users/User/Downloads/angle/angle/build-angle-Desktop-Debug/qtc_Desktop__6e009929-debug/hello-triangle.qtc-Desktop--6e009929.6d1cc0e4/.obj/9ff4caaf6aae2e40/HelloTriangle.cpp.o ^
    -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lANGLE ^
    -langle_common -langle_image_util -lsample_util -ltranslator -lpreprocessor ^
    -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lglew32 -ld3d9 -ld3d11 -ldxguid ^
    -langle_util
```

It seems that there is a problem with `opengl32.dll` dynamic/static loading (which one?). How to solve the problem?

## ADDITIONAL

My mistake: *ANGLE* does not use *OpenGL ES* directly on *Windows*. It translates all the *OpenGL* API calls to DirectX 11 (in my case).

Comment: DLL files must be dynamically loaded.  Try seeing what depends.exe tells you about the executable and the DLL you are trying to load.  Can you please reformat the build lines so they are less than 1000 characters long (cmd supports `^` at the end of the line as a line continuation character)?

Comment: @MartinBonner I'll do immidiately.

Comment: @MartinBonner If I dynamically load (using `windows.h:LoadLibrary`?) required *dlls*, should I load all the required function addresses (using `windows.h:GetProcAddress`?)  (`depends.exe`: `libangle_util.dll` 32bit (in `$PATH`), `c:\windows\system32\{KERNEL32,MSVCRT,OPENGL32}.DLL` 64bit (all in `$PATH`) and `c:\msys64\mingw32\bin\LIB{GCC_S_DW2-1,STDC++}.DLL` 32bit and 64 bit respectively (and these too))? All 32-bit *dlls* are in `$PATH` for sure. I think `depends.exe` slightly wrong (it is 2006' and too old and maybe points on wrong *dlls*).

Comment: Even if I build with `-Wl,-Bdynamic` flag - nothing changes.

Comment: depends.exe is old, but this has been pretty stable for some time now.  It is pointing out the right DLLs.  Note that a 32-bit process can only load 32-bit DLLs, and a 64-bit process can only load 64-bit DLLs.  There is no way to mix bit-edness.

Comment: @MartinBonner Currently I built both 32- and 64-bit versions. The problem exactly the same. I examine all the enviroment (`PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) and it is good.

Comment: @Orient: you're overlooking filesystem redirection for WOW64 (32-bit) processes.  Although they use paths such as `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32`, the actual I/O accesses `C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64`.

Comment: The problem origins from linking against dynamic library alongside with static libraries: dynamic library export all the symbols which are accidentally (because `$LIBS` specified to `make` utility is project-wide) containing in static ones. Also I need to specify `-l:libEGL.a -l:libGLESv2.a` to the linker to force using of the static versions of libraries (`$PATH` containing `libEGL.dll` and `libGLESv2.dll` from `msys2` packages which has priority over static versions).